# What is wrong with my rsync backup sh script?

Tags: backup, rsync

The following is a shell script (backup.sh)

```
rsync -abr --files-from='backup.txt' --delete --stats --progress --exclude={/home/rob} --log-file=/var/log/backup.log /home/ root@remote:/home/
```

I created the above as root. The backup.txt is 4 lines of simple path (/home/linda/ etc..)

I edited crontab to run monday through friday beginning at a certain time.

I can run the script manually and it works fine.

When I leave it to run on it's own and I come back and look at the log, it shows 2 errors:

```
rsync: failed to open files-from file backup.txt: No such file or directory
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1453) [client=3.0.9]
```

What am I doing wrong or forgetting?

Comment: Why curly parenthesis around `/home/rob/`?

Answer (score 2):

Be super-explicit with paths when using cron (or anything where you don't know what environment it's going to be executed from). Use the full path for `backup.txt`.

And the second error could be related to that or it might be blowing up on the curly brackets you've got in `--exclude={/home/rob}`. No idea what you're trying to do there. Just use quotes.

Comment: I have edited the script to reflect the full path to /root/scripts/backup.txt and also replaced the brackets with quotes. I will let it run on it's own to see how it does and report back. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just reporting back that it's working flawlessly! thank you!